# Is there a good way to track the changes in the spell repertoire?

Tags: spells, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e, tools

Spontaneous casters have strict repertoires. A 6th level Sorcerer knows 4 spells from levels 1, 2 and 3 each. You can replace one of them freely on a level-up, or you can spend 7 days of downtime if you do not want to wait<sup>1</sup>.

I would like to see the spells that I have right now, the changes I plan to make, and the end result in a way that is understandable at a glance.

For example, as 3rd level spells I have Animal Vision<sup>2</sup>, Fear, Fireball and Oneiric Mire. Next level I want to replace Fireball with Slow, learn Fireball as a 4th level spell (and make it a signature spell) and of course take 2 more 4th level spells.

I created an Excel sheet for it, the levels are the rows, the each column is a new spell. The leftmost one contains the Bloodline spells, then the other 3 (the signature spell highlighted), and in separate columns the planned retrains. So currently I have two Fireballs in the table, which is very confusing:

[image]

Is there a better way to visualize the data? (current, future, replacements)

---

1. Yes, I see the irony
2. Given by the Bloodline

Comment: I've voted to close as a tool recommendation question, which is what this seems like, although I'm open to being persuaded otherwise. To me, this seems like it's looking for a recommendation for a spell tracker or character builder.

Comment: Voting to leave open in review. This seems to me to be exactly the sort of question we like to see *instead* of a tool recommendation question. It presents a real problem that needs solving: I need an organized method of visualizing my whole spell repertoire at the same time. It then presents an attempt at doing so, that is, *it shows the work and research that has gone into the problem before bringing the problem here*. This seems like a good question to me.

Comment: @ESCE, according to [this answer on meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5883/9552), asking a question where the result _might_ be a tool recommendation is fine, if it is just asking for a solution for a legitimate problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your spells on an excel sheet.

Do a regular wordpad file, line by level.

1. Level 1: Bloodline Spell, Option, Option
2. Level 2: Option
3. Level 3: Bloodline Spell, Option, Option
4. Level 4: Option

Mark your Bloodline Spell with the tag (B). Mark any spell you replace with a strikethrough and an (R#). Mark any Signature spell with an (S). The (B) tag will help you identify which spells you can't swap, the strikethrough(R#) will tell you what level you took a spell, what level you replaced it at(#), and that you no longer have it. (S) Will help you quickly track your current functioning signature spell. You don't have to track when you replace this- just move the tag to the correct spell and confirm time spent to do so with the DM.

If you replace a spell during a level, add the new spell (and its level) to that level's line, and tag with (R-old spell name) which should point you to the spell you've applied a strike-through to for reference.